# How can I make this stop taking 30 minutes to grow the grid?

Tags: python, pygame, grid, path-finding

Takes forever to "grow the grid" in this pathfinding algorithm and sometimes it just straight up crashes. How can I iterate more efficiently? There is some functionality that I haven't implemented yet such as skip wall blocks and find value (cost * distance) which is why it doesn't seem to do a whole bunch yet.

Here is my code:

```
#add all x and y axis coordinates to arrays
def CreateGridCoordinates():
    x = 0
    for i in range(0, 24):
        gridXCoordinates.append(x)
        gridYCoordinates.append(x)
        x+=20;

CreateGridCoordinates()

#get grid coordinates and create black wall
def GetGridCoordinatesIndexAndCreateWall():
    #get mouse location
    mousex, mousey = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    for y in range(0, 24):
        for x in range(0, 24):
            #check each square for mouse location
            if mousex >= gridXCoordinates[x] and mousex <= (gridXCoordinates[x] + gridXCoordinates[1]) and mousey >= gridYCoordinates[y] and mousey <= (gridYCoordinates[y] + gridYCoordinates[1]):
                #create wall cell and paint it black
                wallCell = GridCell(black)
                wallCell.rect.x = gridXCoordinates[x]
                wallCell.rect.y = gridXCoordinates[y]
                wallCells.add(wallCell)

    global wallCellsBool
    wallCellsBool = True

#create backdrop grid
def CreateCells():
    cellX = 0
    cellY = 0
    for i in range(0, 24):
        for e in range(0, 24):
            cell = GridCell(grey)
            cell.rect.x = cellX
            cell.rect.y = cellY
            bgCells.add(cell)
            cellX+=20
        cellY+=20
        cellX = 0
        
    return bgCells

pathFinderCellX = 0
pathFinderCellY = 0

#create start cell
startCell = GridCell(pink)
startCell.rect.x = pathFinderCellX
startCell.rect.y = pathFinderCellY
pathFinderCells.add(startCell)

#create end cell
endCell = GridCell(green)
endCell.rect.x = gridXCoordinates[23]
endCell.rect.y = gridYCoordinates[23]
finishCell.add(endCell)

#create path finder cell
def CreatePathFinderCell(x, y):
    global pathFinderCellX, pathFinderCellY
    pathFinderCell = GridCell(pink)
    pathFinderCellX+=x
    pathFinderCellY+=y
    pathFinderCell.rect.x = pathFinderCellX
    pathFinderCell.rect.y = pathFinderCellY
    pathFinderCells.add(pathFinderCell)

#decide where pathfinder should be created
def MovePathFinder(direction):
    if direction == "up":
        print("up")
        CreatePathFinderCell(0, -cellSpace)
    elif direction == "down":
        print("down")
        CreatePathFinderCell(0, cellSpace)
    elif direction == "left":
        print("left")
        CreatePathFinderCell(-cellSpace, 0)
    elif direction == "right":
        print("right")
        CreatePathFinderCell(cellSpace, 0)

#save distance and cost of movement

growthCellX = 0
growthCellY = 0

boolCellGrowth = False

def CheckFinish(x, y):
    for finishcell in finishCell:
        if finishcell.rect.x != x and finishcell.rect.y != y:
            boolCellGrowth = False
            break

def CheckWallAndBounds(x, y):
    if wallCellsBool == True:
        for wallcell in wallCells:
                if wallcell.rect.x != x and wallcell.rect.y != y:
                    return True
                else:
                    return False

def DontReplace(x, y):
    for growthcell in growthCells:
        if growthcell.rect.x == x and growthcell.rect.y == y:
            return True
        else:
            return False

#create growth cells
def CreateNewGrowthCell(x, y): 
    if CheckWallAndBounds(x, y) == True or DontReplace(x, y) == True:
        growthCell = GridCell(lightPink)
        growthCell.rect.x = x
        growthCell.rect.y = y
        growthCells.add(growthCell)
        #calculate distance from growth to finish
        #calculate distance from start to growth
    
complete = True

def CellGrowthByOne():
    global complete
    for e in growthCells:
        #from each cell create 8 surrounding cells
        growthSpaceX = e.rect.x
        growthSpaceY = e.rect.y
        CreateNewGrowthCell(growthSpaceX, (growthSpaceY - 20))
        CreateNewGrowthCell((growthSpaceX - 20), (growthSpaceY - 20))
        CreateNewGrowthCell((growthSpaceX - 20), growthSpaceY)
        CreateNewGrowthCell((growthSpaceX - 20), (growthSpaceY + 20))
        CreateNewGrowthCell(growthSpaceX, (growthSpaceY + 20))
        CreateNewGrowthCell((growthSpaceX + 20), (growthSpaceY + 20))
        CreateNewGrowthCell((growthSpaceX + 20), growthSpaceY)
        CreateNewGrowthCell((growthSpaceX + 20), (growthSpaceY - 20))
```

I tried to add a couple of break statements.

Comment: There's quite a lot of code there. Please reduce this to a [mre], emphasis on "minimal".

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

The function `GetGridCoordinatesIndexAndCreateWall` can be greatly simplified. The row and column of a cell can be obtained by dividing the mouse coordinates by the size of the cell with the `//` (floor division) operator:

```py
column = mousex // 20
row    = mousey // 20
```

The `GetGridCoordinatesIndexAndCreateWall` function may look as follows:

```py
cell_size = 20
columns, rows = 24, 24

def GetGridCoordinatesIndexAndCreateWall():
    
    mousex, mousey = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    if mousex < columns * cell_size and mousey < rows * cell_size:

        column = mousex // cell_size 
        row    = mousey // cell_size 

        wallCell = GridCell(black)
        wallCell.rect.x = column * cell_size
        wallCell.rect.y = row * cell_size
        wallCells.add(wallCell)
```